# JavaFX 3D - Scene Camera Issues, SubScene Errors, and MeshViews not Visible

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-3d

I will try to be as brief as possible while providing enough info so that someone might be able to help point me in the right direction.  I am trying to add a 3D scene to the center or a borderpane that will contain a set of meshviews that I read from an obj file using an obj loader that has been well tested by others (so I'm confident it works).  I will give my summary step by step and provide an image to show my progress and issues.
I start with my borderpane empty:
[image]
Next, I started by taking an example from a book that add me create three primitives and add them to a scene and changed it so that this is added to the center part of my borderpane.  I created a method that is tied to the File/Open action that when I click File/Open, it calls that method and creates the primitives and adds them to the center of the borderpane:
[image]
Next, I tried to add a camera to the main scene that is created as part of the initial Application start method using the following lines: 
(line 29 to 33 were commented out in earlier pictures)
[image]
However, this leads to the following issue where the borderpane is projected into the third dimension:
[image]
I then tried using a SubScene in the center of the borderpane but kept getting a lot of errors of the type nullpointerexception and the info was too vague for me to use to figure out what it was not happy about.
The other and more important issue that I am dealing with while trying to figure this out, is the final version meant to read a group of meshviews from an obj file and add them to the center does not work.  The code reads the obj file and imports the meshviews from it.  I have printed out to the console number of meshviews read and it matches what was in the test file, so I feel confident I'm using it correctly and this loader has been used a lot by others so has been tested.  But when I try to change out and use that to add meshviews to the center I just get a blank center screen and a console printout showing it read the file and that it read the correct number of meshviews.  I have not been able to find a good way to debug/figure this out.  so could use some advice on that as well.
Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: please paste your code don't take pics

Comment: Post a [mcve]. Hint: if the object loader is not a problem, create a simple shape from JavaFX as your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of
`Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane,sceneWidth,sceneHeight);`

add this

```
Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane,sceneWidth,sceneHeight,true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
```

the last two parameters are = depthBuffer  and antialiasing